# How do you determine native american ancestry?

Tags: native-american

How would you determine how much cherokee indian in your heritage is your great great grandmother was 1/2 cherokee indian?

Answer (score 1):

For every generation, divide by 2. Your great-grandmother was 1/4 Cherokee, your grandmother 1/8 Cherokee, your mother 1/16 Cherokee, and you are 1/32 Cherokee, assuming that no other of your ancestors had Cherokee blood (actually, DNA).

If your Cherokee ancestor was your mother's mother's mother's mother, you would have 100% Cherokee mitochondrial DNA, which is passed down on the maternal line.